# How can I get specific data out of a list (with lists) under a certain condition

Tags: r, list, loops

I have lists in lists and would like to take the activities that occur just within the first 600 seconds (journey time < 600). The "journey time" starts with 0 and adds the time of corresponding activity "code" on top.

**homepage1[["customer_data"]][["activity_list"]][[i]][["journey_time"]]**

**homepage1[["customer_data"]][["activity_list"]][[i]][["code"]]**

So for example [["journey_time"]] could look like this 0, 46.7, 79.4, ...., 1800.

[["code"]] looks like StartPage, ClickItem1, ScrollItem1, ..., ClosePage.

"i" are the customers here.

I tried it for each customer alone, but I, of course, would prefer an iterative process with loops.

Thank you in advance! Appreciate it much!

Marius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure looks like a `JSON -> R` conversion, so in case you have the original `JSON` you may not need to convert it to `JSON` first.

Having said this, you can use `fromJSON` with `flatten = TRUE` to get the relevant data in a nice `data.frame` format, which makes the processing much easier:

#### Data

```r
homepage1 <- list(
  customer_data = list(
    activity_list = list(
       list(
          list(journey_time = 0, code = "StartPage"),
          list(journey_time = 46.7, code = "ClickItem1"),
          list(journey_time = 79.4, code = "ScrollItem1"),
          list(journey_time = 1800, code = "ClosePage")
       )
    )
  )
)
```

```r
library(jsonlite)
(mdat <- fromJSON(toJSON(homepage1), flatten = TRUE))
# $customer_data
# $customer_data$activity_list
# $customer_data$activity_list[[1]]
#   journey_time        code
# 1            0   StartPage
# 2         46.7  ClickItem1
# 3         79.4 ScrollItem1
# 4         1800   ClosePage
```

So all you need to do is to use `cumsum` on column `journey_time` (assuming that each timing measures the time spent on the element since the **last visit** and not from the **beginning**, if the later is true you do not need `cumsum`) to get cumulative timings and use that as a filter:

```r
idx <- cumsum(mdat$customer_data$activity_list[[1]]$journey_time) < 600
unlist(mdat$customer_data$activity_list[[1]]$code[idx])
# [1] "StartPage"   "ClickItem1"  "ScrollItem1"
```

Now it is easy to loop over **all** customers like this:

```r
lapply(mdat$customer_data$activity_list, function(al) {
   idx <- cumsum(al$journey_time) < 600
   unlist(al$code[idx])
})
```

Comment: Great, thank you! It worked! In case I would like to compress similar subsequent activities (so in case two times "ClickItem1"  "ClickItem1" should be compressed afterward, so to just get one "ClickItem1". I used the following code since I was working with data frames:
dplyr::mutate(previous_activity_code=dplyr::lag(df1)
dplyr::filter(df1=previous_activity_code) 

How can I apply this code to the new list? Thanks again!

Comment: I would propose you share a snippet of your data, this would make answering your question so much easier. If you like my answer I owuld be very happy if you upvote and or accept it.